# Using file to exchange messages between two processes

Tags: c#, excel, inter-process-communicat

I am creating a C# program that outputs data to excel using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

In excel I have 5 user defined functions (UDF) that when executed I will like to call a method on my C# application. The way I am planing on trigering a method on C# is on excel I will write to a file named `someFile.txt` I will write `1` to it. Then on my C# application I will read that `1` and because I read a 1 I will trigger method 1 for instance. One process (excel) will write to the file and the other process (c# program) will read from that file. In other words https://stackoverflow.com/a/222111/637142.

I know it will be more appropiate to create an XLL, or used named pipes. The problem is I know very little visual basic and I believe writing one byte to a file (1,2,3,4 or 5) should be very quick. So using this implementation is a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a terrible way to do inter process communication. You might get away with it if this a quick and dirty app to do a specific task and it won't ever escape "to the wild", but if this is something that needs to exist long term, put the effort into doing it correctly. WCF is dead easy to use.

Comment: Have you considered to use a WCF service? That is called from the excel macro just as an usual REST or SOAP web service?

Comment: I know I love WCF but I have no idea how to create the client code from VBA in excel. Perhaps I should google WCF for excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a WebService inside Excel [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474936/call-web-service-in-excel)

In your C# application you can write a simple basic WCF [see this example](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2010/11/30/hosting-wcf-service-in-a-console-application/)