# Accessing a file that was locked by a third party library used by the same process

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-locking

I'm using a third party library in my .NET Core console application. The library is generating a text file and the library keeps the file locked (possibly a static instance is kept somewhere inside the library) until the process exits.

I need to postprocess the locked file after I have done calling the third-party library functions. Of course, currently I cannot do that because of the infamous "The file is being used by another process" exception (in my case, it's actually the same process).

**What would be the easiest and safest approach to gain access to the locked file from the same console application?**

Fortunately, I know for sure there will be no parallel threads running and no more other access to this file - once the library is done writing, it is done, although the file remains locked. So, I could safely do whatever I like with the file if only I could "break the lock" or invent some trick to unload that third party library and get the lock released.

Comment: Maybe the FileShare allows you to read as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097773/system-io-filestream-fileaccess-vs-fileshare

Comment: `FileShare.ReadWrite` got me halfway - I could read the contents but when I tried to write it back I got `Stream is not writable` exception. So, I guess the library has locked the file for writing.

Comment: Have you closed/disposed all resources from the library? It is not normal to keep a file open, unless the "process" is not completely finished.

Comment: The library documentation asks to initialize it with DI `ServiceCollection`. I tried to make sure that my ServiceCollection instance is null-ified and out of scope when I attempt to write to the file, but still that did not help - most probably, there are some crossreferences.

Comment: You could try making your own DI Scope, then do a `myscope.ServiceProvider.RequiredService<T>` and call the "process". Afterwards Dispose the scope.

Comment: Thank you, this approach helped, but only after I added             `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` after disposing the scope. I guess, some references were still stuck and only forced GC collection got rid of them and finally closed the file handle.